# SSRS Report Row Hide issue

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix

I am new to SSRS Reports, I am facing following problem :

I need to show some data and its total. But total must be in different formats like **Date wise Total**, **Employee Wise Total**, **Area Wise Total** . So, I added these groups like Parent Group : Area, in it child group Employee, then child group Date. Now I have condition that if some particular columns are zero hide whole row, which I achieved. But its Date wise total row, Employee Wise Total row,is not getting hidden which is below the actual data row. Mine expression is only working on actual data row but not on my total's row.

Where should I place expression for that, and what will be the possible expression.

Answer (score 0):

Use SUM for group visibility

Eg if detail hidden expression  is

= ( Fields!A.Value = 0 AND Fields!B.Value = 0)

Then the group hidden expression should be the aggregate

= ( SUM(Fields!A.Value) = 0 AND SUM(Fields!B.Value) = 0)